# Summarising the Distribution of Values Within A Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

Here is my data:

```
{'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
1: '5F891F03',
2: '5F891F03',
3: '5F891F03',
4: '95EE8B57'},
'Activity': {0: '2', 1: '4', 2: '6',   3: '8', 4: '1'}}
```

I need to summarise the dataset on "Activity". For each "SystemID" I need to calculate the *percentage* that falls within each of 4 categories: less than 2, 2 or greater but less than 4, 4 or greater but less than 6, 6 or greater.

The result for the above snippet would be:

```
{'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
1: '5F891F03'},
'Activity-perc-less2': {0: '50', 1: '0'},
'Activity-perc-less4': {0: '50', 1: '0'},
'Activity-perc-less6': {0: '0', 1: '33.3'},
'Activity-perc-6-and-above': {0: '0', '66.7'}}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the most elegant way to do it but the following seems to produce what I wanted:

```
dict2 = {'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
1: '5F891F03',
2: '5F891F03',
3: '5F891F03',
4: '95EE8B57'},
'Activity': {0: '2', 1: '4', 2: '6',   3: '8', 4: '1'}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)
bins = np.array([2, 4, 6])
df2.Activity = df2.Activity.astype(int)

#Solution:

df2['ActBins'] = np.digitize(df2.Activity, bins)
table = pd.pivot_table(df2, index=["SystemID"],columns=["ActBins"], 
                   aggfunc=len, margins=True, dropna=True,fill_value=0)
table2 = 100*table.div( table.iloc[:,-1], axis=0 )
table3 = table2.iloc[[0,1],[0,1,2,3]]
table3.columns = ['Activity-perc-less2', 'Activity-perc-less4', 
'Activity-perc-less6', 'Activity-perc-6-and-above']
print(table3)
```

If anyone finds some more elegant solution, please, post it.

EDIT:

Just abstracted away the above solution as a function:

```
def perc_pivot (df, ind, col, bin):
  df[col+'Bins'] = np.digitize(df[col], bins)
  table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=[ind],columns=[col+'Bins'], 
           aggfunc=len, margins=True, dropna=True,fill_value=0)
  table = 100*table.div( table.iloc[:,-1], axis=0 )
  table.drop(table.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
  return  table.drop(table.columns[len(table.columns)-1], axis=1)
```

A simple call

```
df3 = perc_pivot(df2, 'SystemID', 'Activity', bins)
```

produces the desired output (apart from the column names). The renaming of the columns can be done manually afterwards.

The code in the function still looks a bit clunky to me so I would welcome suggestions that might make it more elegant.